# Running two puma servers at once for the same rails project, force kills one of the servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I would like to run two Rails servers from the same directory, on different ports. Here's what I have tried:

1. `rails s`, which starts my server on port 3000.
2. In another terminal tab, I run `puma -p 7676`, which starts another server on port 7676.

No matter what order I run these commands, whether I switch out `puma` for `rails s`, one of the servers always gets shut down.

The error it shows is:

`A server is already running. Check /Users/<username>/<appname>/tmp/pids/server.pid.`

Now, following several stack overflow answers, it seems you can tell the command where it should look for the pid:

1. `rails s`
2. `` rails s -p 3007 -P `pwd`/tmp/pids/alternative_server.pid ``

This fails with the exact same error:

`A server is already running. Check /Users/<username>/<appname>/tmp/pids/server.pid.`

So far my only recourse has been to clone my project in a seperate directory and run the server from there. This is obviously not ideal since I need to keep pulling any changes I make on the branch.

Versions:

1. Puma: `Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112)`
2. Rails: `5.0.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to comment `plugin :tmp_restart` in `config/puma.rb`.

This is source code of this plugin: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/plugin/tmp_restart.rb

Comment: Interesting. Thank you so much for the answer. I knew there was an issue regarding the puma restart plugin, but have never checked my config for a puma file!